# How to locate JavaScript code responsive for button action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, webforms

There is a button that, when clicked, does a specific action and refreshes the page. Its looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="name" value="some value" id="mt1_main_btn" class="btn_next">
```

When I try to copy that obviously it does not work because there is not JavaScript behind it to do what its supposed do.  Is there any way to find on the page whats triggering it to work and copy that over to the new pages? What is the best thing to look for?

Comment: A submit button when clicked submits the relevant FORM http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html  So look at the FORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is to find an element modified by the action that's taking place (let's say maybe clicking causes something to hide or show on the page)

By right clicking on an element in Chrome's Elements panel, you have the option to break on subtree modification:

http://monosnap.com/image/VmtTNLmDt6c3twbLT8hEEj7p7M80JM

What this means is that if a DOM node inside this element changes, the javascript execution will pause.

This will let you investigate the stack:

http://monosnap.com/image/ZD8ZYTqNPNX2Ee1BybVGpGc2BMcniV

I'd look at that first file that's not jQuery to see what code is executing.

Answer (score 1):

that depends on a few things.  First, I'd search the page source for javascript scripts and/or POSTs, because those would be performing an action (in this case, looks like it's a POST).  Once you find the request that is actually enacted when the button's pressed, you'll be able to see which page contains the code processing the information sent in the POST, and possibly read it.  If the site author is hiding what's actually processing information, you're not gonna be able to read it, but otherwise, in the chrome source inspector, you can read some of the scripts the page refers to by clicking on "Sources."  Also, just explore.  Press control-U and just stare at that page until you understand it.  HTML is actually pretty cool.  Best of luck.